# Un-set a property by overriding it

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, profile, properties-file

I have a logistical Problem with spring property files. Im doing a refactor of our profiles with the following goal:

I want to have two configurations in which I want to start the application. One for local development and one for the production environment. I know the property values for both configurations. The aim is to have the default profile act as the local configuration and have just one profile 'production' which will overwrite values for the production scenario.

The problem is now that the local configuration sets some properties which the production config does not set. So in any case where the production config is an extension of the local (i.e. default) config, there will be some properties which are set to some value which should actually be undefined.

Is there some way by which I can "un-set" these properties in the production profile?

**Example** of how I would like it to work:

```
# application.properties

# this is the local configuration
app.config.name = "FOO"
services.search.url = localhost:8081
app.mock.provider = localhost:8082
```

.

```
# application-production.properties

# activating this should yield the production configuration 
services.search.url = production-search-url.com # Overriding works of course
app.mock.provider = PLEASE_MAKE_THIS_PROP_UNDEFINED_AGAIN # I suppose this doesn't work   
spring.sentry.dns = nw9x74b3kqllanx6rh3
# app.config.name = "FOO" should be and is still set
```

Comment: Well in the project which I am working on, property files are located in git ignore list, which means that you can keep your local property file without worrying about that, and when changes are required on production we do the changes through ssh on the file itself.

Comment: The devs will be able to change their local config through an overrides profile whose property files is on git ignore. I didn't include that fact in the question because I thought it wasn't relevant.